# What is the fastest way to find which of the substrings is present in a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, substring

Okay, may be the question was weird.
Let me explain a case in hand. I have 5 names in an array
eg:

```
var namesArray=['John','Henry','Smith','James','Carl'];
```

And I also have a string from some other operation which contains one of these strings with a salutation, say `Hello John` or `Mr.John` (note that there is no space in the second one).

```
var returnedName='Howdy,James!';
```

What I do know is that the returning string will contain only one of the strings in the mentioned `namesArray` and no more, and I have no knowledge about the surrounding characters the string may have in `returnedName`.

What is the fastest way to know which of the strings in the `namesArray` is a substring of `returnedName`? I was expecting a function which returns the index of the string in `namesArray` which is a substring of `returnedName`. Does such an in-built function exist? If not, what would be the fastest (I have a namesArray of about 100k names, say) way to do that?

Comment: This would answer your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296268/fastest-way-to-check-a-string-contain-another-substring-in-javascript

Comment: if `namesArray` contains `Carl` and the `returnedName` contains `Carlito` - how would you handle that?

Comment: I would still want the index of Carl to be returned, as it is a valid substring. One one valid substring is possible in my case, the names were just a way to give an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be more like a searching problem. Obviously, while searching you do need to make a comparison to match your search term. For this w.r.t. your problem, in JavaScript you can think of [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). But to make it faster for better time complexity you'll have to think of some better search algorithm (Binary Search may be) than a linear iteration over array.

Answer (score 1):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf, if I understand well your question.

With a for loop indeed...

See [Javascript Performance: How come looping through an array and checking every value is faster than indexOf, search and match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774366/javascript-performance-how-come-looping-through-an-array-and-checking-every-val) or [Fastest way to check a string contain another substring in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296268/fastest-way-to-check-a-string-contain-another-substring-in-javascript) for more precisions about performances issues.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to check if string contains another substring.

```
var str = "Hello world, welcome to Javascript Coding.";
var n = str.indexOf("welcome");

//Returns Index no 13

var s = "foo";
console.log(s.indexOf("oo") > -1)

//returns true
```

You could also use string.includes method to achieve the same result

```
var str = "Hello World, Welcome to Javascript Coding";

console.log(str.includes("Welcome to"));    // true
console.log(str.includes("Javascript")); // true
console.log(str.includes("To be", 1)); // false
```

Reference article [How to check if string contains another substring](http://code.askmein.com/how-to-check-if-string-contains-another-substring/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over the array, checking if the string contains the array value, and if it does, break the loop (as there can be only one) and set a variable :

```
var containsName = '';

for (var i=0; i<namesArray.length; i++) {
    if ( returnedName.indexOf( namesArray[i] ) != -1 ) {
        containsName = namesArray[i];
        break;
    }
}

alert( containsName );
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FqVKG/)