# Adding comma separators into calculation result

Tags: javascript

How can I have comma separators displayed in the calculation results?
(123456789 to show as 123,456,789)

```
function calculate(){
a=Number(document.calculator.number1.value);
b=Number(document.calculator.number2.value);

A1=a*2000
document.calculator.totalA1.value=A1;
A2=a*b*240
document.calculator.totalA2.value=A2;
A3=a*8*240
document.calculator.totalA3.value=A3;
A4=a*960*5
document.calculator.totalA4.value=A4;
A5=a*3600*5
document.calculator.totalA5.value=A5;
A6=a*3000
document.calculator.totalA6.value=A6;
A7=A1+A2+A3+A4+A5+A6
document.calculator.totalA7.value=A7;
A8=a*120000
document.calculator.totalA8.value=A8;
A9=A8-A7
document.calculator.totalA9.value=A9;
}
```

I've seen many suggestions but don't know where to insert the script.
Thanks!

Comment: You mean like 2,000? Just stringsplit the number and insert commas every 3 chars.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this using [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```js
$("#button").click(function(){
  var a = 100;
  var A1=(a*2000);
  alert(String(A1).replace(/(\d{3})(?!$)/g, "$1,"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="button">Calculate </button>
```

Comment: Interesting solution, too.

Comment: Thanks, i've just started learning how regex works so I hope it is indeed a valid solution.

Comment: What I wonder is if the regex or the for loop solution is more performant, unfortunately jsperf seems to be down at the moment.

Comment: I have no idea haha. From my limited knowledge, i'd assume a loop would be more costly, is that right? I haven't a clue about how how code affects performance yet, I should definitely start reading up on that!

Comment: Doesn't look like it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oanapl/2009/04/04/performance-comparison-regex-versus-string-operations/ And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774366/javascript-performance-how-come-looping-through-an-array-and-checking-every-val

Comment: I didn't know that, that is interesting! In the OP's use-case scenario, which i'm assuming is a calculator, do you think the performance would be greatly affected by using regex? Because I am using regex in some of my projects instead of your method and I am now considering re-writing my code

Comment: For this little piece of code performance is totally negligible I'd say. Also I've just read different statements about the performance of regex vs for loop, not sure any more if my solution is indeed faster or I am probably mistaken.

Comment: Oh okay, I think I am going to start using jsperf from now on and compare different bits of code and learn how to optimise my code. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/odewuqun/3/

```
function addPunctuation(number){
    var array = number.toString().split("");
    var output = "";
    var first = true;
    for(var i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if((array.length-i-1) % 3 === 0){
        if(first){
          first = false;
        }else{
          output = "," + output;
        }      
      }
      output = array[i] + output;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Short explanation:

- Convert the number into a String.
- Split that String into an array.
- Iterate over that array from the end and make a new String where you add a , between every 3 chars.

That is archieved by index % 3 === 0. (% is the mathematic modulo operator for whole number division with rest)